# how do you display the full description of a helm revision?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I had a helm upgrade fail, and I now want to see the full description. Right now, it only gives the first 57 characters of the error message and I have not been able to find how to display it in full on SO or in the helm docs.

`helm history my-name` yields:

```
REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART       APP VERSION         DESCRIPTION
...
9           Tue Jun 16 20:38:53 2020    FAILED      my-chart    my-version          Upgrade "my-name" failed: Deployment.apps "something...
```

`helm status --revision 9 my-name` only yields:

```
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Jun 16 20:38:53 2020
NAMESPACE: my-namespace
STATUS: FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it! you can change the max width of the output with:

```
helm history my-name --col-width 1000
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with helm v3.4.1, it prints `Error: unknown flag: --col-width`

Answer (score 0):

For helm v3.4.1 I managed to get the entire description by asking helm to provide output in JSON format: `-o json`.

Like this:

```
helm history my-name -o json
```

Answer (score 0):

`helm history my-name --col-width 1000` also does not work for me.

```
~ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.13.1", GitCommit:"3547a4b5bf5edb5478ce352e18858d8a552a4110", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.20.8"}
```

`helm history chariot -o yaml`

worked for me and showed the whole error.

what version of helm are you on?